In filamentphp, how to fill the fields of a form with the login user profile data?
I'm working with Filamentphp, and I've created a "Report" resource. When creating a Report I want to automatically fill in data from the logged in user to the form.
Forms\Components\TextInput::make('employee_name')
          ->label('Made by:')
          ->default(here load the name of the logged in user found in the profile table)
          ->disabled()
          ->dehydrated(),

At the same time I need to do the same but from the 'departments' table
Forms\Components\TextInput::make('department')
          ->label('Department')
          ->default(here load the name of the logged in user found in the department table)
          ->disabled()
          ->dehydrated(),

I already have my models with their relationships ready.
User Model
public function profile() 
{
  return $this->hasOne(Profile::class); 
}

Departement Model
public function profile(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Profile::class);
}

Profile Model
public function department()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
}
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

I tried with a function, but it gives me an error.
Forms\Components\TextInput::make('employee_name')
              ->label('Made by:')
              ->default(function () {
                $data['name'] = \App\Models\Profile::query()->where('user_id', auth()->id());
                return $data;
              })
              ->disabled()
              ->dehydrated(),


I think that because you return an array, but the field expect you return a string. You can try this
Forms\Components\TextInput::make('employee_name')
              ->label('Made by:')
              ->default(fn() => auth()->user()->profile->full_name) \\ depends what property that you want to be saved
              ->disabled()
              ->dehydrated(),


That works fine. Thank you.
